# Why pulling package from packagist is failing?

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I have forked a repository to make some changes in it. Here is my repo

> https://github.com/vinsaj9/scrypt

and it has tags too. It is linked with packagist

> https://packagist.org/packages/vinsaj9/scrypt

Now, I am getting following error

> "The requested package vinsaj9/scrypt could not be found in any
> version, there may be a typo in the package name"

when I am trying to pull it through this composer setting

```
{
    "name": "test/test",
    "description": "test",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "license": "OSL-3.0",
    "require": {
        "vinsaj9/scrypt": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: You perhaps were too eager and packagist not yet updated. It should install just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre) mentioned in his comment to my question. After uploading package to https://packagist.org/ you need to wait for some hours. In my case it was not updated even after 4 hours and reason could be that I was keep making changes in the repo, creating new releases and tags in the process of debugging my problem.